# Perl regex alternation

Tags: regex, perl

I have the following strings:

```
Data 250 MB
Data 1.5 GB
Data 10 GB
```

I need to capture only the values `250 MB, 1.5 GB, 10 GB`. So I wrote the expression

`(my $data) = $str1 =~ /Data (\S+ GB|MB)/ or die "$str1\n";`

This works for the data in GB, but for MB, I get the result `Data 250 MB`. Can anyone please explain why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You defined your capture group as `(\S+ GB|MB)` which matches `\S+ GB` **or** `MB` (i.e. `|` is applied to whole capture group).

You want either:

1. `/Data (\S+ GB|\S+ MB)/`
2. `/Data (\S+ (GB|MB))/`, or even better `/Data (\S+ (?:GB|MB))/`, utilizing non-capture group.

Answer (score 8):

The alternation operator doesn't operate on words, it means

```
(\S+ GB) or (MB)
```

Add non-capturing parentheses:

```
/Data (\S+ (?:GB|MB))/
```

which you can further simplify with a character class:

```
/Data (\S+ [GM]B)/
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
(my $data) = $str1 =~ /Data (\S+ [GM]B)/ or die "$str1\n";
```

It will match **G**B or **M**B